# Outlook 2013 Calendar Search for Attedees

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, calendar

In Outlook 2013 calendar, I am trying to find an old meeting by searching for one of the attendees at the meeting.  Is there a way to search in the calendar for such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to click in the Search box in the upper-right of calendar view. This should enable the search ribbon at the top of the screen.

Under the **Refine** section click the down arrow on **More**.

You can then choose to search for Optional Attendees or Required Attendees.

[image]